# Gemini Exchange REST API Private Endpoints Requiring 3 or More Parameters using R

Tags: r, rest, authentication, post

I'm using R to interact with the Gemini exchange API (https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/) for private endpoints. I've been able to reduce my problem to endpoints which require more than 2 parameters in the payload. In particular I'm attempting to query the /v1/mytrades endpoint (https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#get-past-trades) which I believe requires the 'request', 'nonce' and 'symbol' parameters at a minimum. The error code I receive is HTTP 400 which Gemini describes as:

> Auction not open or paused, ineligible timing, market not open, or the request was malformed; in the case of a private API request, missing or malformed Gemini private API authentication headers

I have no issues with other endpoints which require only the 'request' and 'nonce' parameters, so I'm struggling to understand which step is a problem since those queries require similar steps to create a base64 encoding of the payload, a signature of that encoding using the API secret and headers with that data plus the API key.

Below is my example code where MY_API_SECRET and MY_API_KEY are placeholders for the actual secret and key strings

```
#   Set variable for the gemini api URL
geminiHost <- "https://api.gemini.com"
#   Set variable for the gemini endpoint
geminiEndpoint <- "/v1/mytrades"
#   Create the symbol parameter
symbol <- 'btcusd'
#   Create nonce parameter
currentTimeNonce <- round(as.numeric(Sys.time()) * 1000, 0)
#   Create JSON payload
payload <-
    toJSON(data.frame(
        request = geminiEndpoint,
        nonce = currentTimeNonce,
        symbol = symbol
    )) %>% gsub("\\[|\\]", "", .)
#   Convert payload to base64
payloadBase64Enc <- base64_enc(payload)
#   Create signature
signatureString <- sha384(payloadBase64Enc, key = 'MY_API_SECRET')
#   Construct the complete URL
completeURL <- paste0(geminiHost, geminiEndpoint)
#   Create header
hdr = c(
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain",
    "Content-Length" = "0",
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache",
    "X-GEMINI-APIKEY" = "MY_API_KEY",
    "X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD" = payloadBase64Enc,
    "X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE" = signatureString
)
#   Request API using the complete URL and the required headers
mytradesAPIResult <- fromJSON(httpPOST(completeURL,
                                       httpheader = hdr,
                                       verbose = TRUE))
```

For comparison, the following code which requests the /v1/orders endpoint (https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#get-active-orders) does indeed come back with a response:

```
#   Set variable for the gemini api URL
geminiHost <- "https://api.gemini.com"
#   Set variable for the gemini endpoint
geminiEndpoint <- "/v1/orders"
#   Create nonce parameter
currentTimeNonce <- round(as.numeric(Sys.time()) * 1000, 0)
#   Create JSON payload
payload <-
    toJSON(data.frame(request = geminiEndpoint, nonce = currentTimeNonce)) %>%
    gsub("\\[|\\]", "", .)
#   Convert payload to base64
payloadBase64Enc <- base64_enc(payload)
#   Create signature
signatureString <- sha384(payloadBase64Enc, key = 'MY_API_SECRET')
#   Construct the complete URL
completeURL <- paste0(geminiHost, geminiEndpoint)
#   Create header
hdr = c(
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain",
    "Content-Length" = "0",
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache",
    "X-GEMINI-APIKEY" = "MY_API_KEY",
    "X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD" = payloadBase64Enc,
    "X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE" = signatureString
)
#   Request API using the complete URL and the required headers
mytradesAPIResult <- fromJSON(httpPOST(completeURL,
                                       httpheader = hdr,
                                       verbose = TRUE))
```

So in the latter code the only difference is the geminiEndpoint and payload construction which as mentioned above only has 2 required parameters (request and nonce). To expand further, I'm successfully hitting other endpoints such as /v1/tradevolume, /v1/heartbeat, and /v1/balances that also require those 2 parameters only while /v1/order/status is another example of an endpoint requiring at least 3 parameters that doesn't work for me.

I appreciate any help to understand where I'm going wrong with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to get it to work in a browser and/or using `wget` or `curl`? I'm not familiar with Gemini, but this may not be specific to R.

Comment: r2evans, thank  you! I did not try getting this to work using something like a bash script with curl. As I was working through that method and testing the equivalent base64 encoding, I saw some weird results from my R script which isolated the problem. Following up with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I started to work on an equivalent bash script based on r2evans' reply when I found my issue. It was the base64 encoding step in R that resulted in some unusual output. As seen in my original scripts, I was using the "base64_enc()" function which is part of the jsonlite package. As a simple check I was trying to confirm that the encoding from R was equal to an equivalent encoding using base64 in shell so I started by trying to decode the R result.

In R, the encoding of the payload for the 3 parameter example was coming out with a backslash character '\' which is not valid Base64 and points to my misunderstanding of what the base64_enc function is doing. I replaced this function with **base64_encode** from the **openssl package** and now my 3 parameter queries are coming back with results.